# Chrome speed dial

Tags: google-chrome, speed-dial

I recently signed up for Trello (excellent on-line collaborative to-do lists) and added trello.com to my speed dial in Chrome (I'm on the latest version).

Even though I've visited the site several times using the speed dial ("Preview is not ready, click to create preview"), it hasn't created a preview yet, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by you “added it to the speed-dial”? Are you using a third-party extension or the one built-into the NTP of Chrome? If you are using the default one, have you restarted the browser at all?

Comment: It's the Speed Dial for Chrome extension v2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's a conflict between the latest Chrome and Speed Dial (I've logged the issue with the entension author via the Chrome web store), only on https pages, I've found this work-around.

I located the directory where Speed Dial installs to (thanks @Synetech). On Windows XP should be something like:

C:\Documents and Settings\[My username]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi\2.5.1_0\images

Although there were no thumbnail images in this folder, I created my own folder under images entitled "mine": ..\2.5.1_0\images\mine

I then copied a screenshot I'd taken using [Google Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) into this directory as "trello.png".

The last step was to go to "Edit Dial" and type "images/mine/trello.png" into the "Dial Image URL" box (you can also load images from any url such as [photobucket](http://photobucket.com/)).

Clicking save then immediately displayed my screenshot as the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be patient; it will eventually update it. Several of the sites in my most-visited list got broken-site thumbnails because I tried to visit them while disconnected. It has been a few days since then and a couple of them are *still* showing the broken page preview while a few others have updated.

(If you really want to know what triggers and times Chrome uses to update the thumbnails, you can peruse the [source code](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).)

If you are impatient, you can try to force it by deleting the file `Thumbnails` in your [user-data folder](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), but it may still take a few visits before it updates them.

Comment: It's looking like a bug/conflict between the Chrome and Speed Dial, but only for https pages.